# MVC5 Azure Active Directory Role-Based Authentication Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC5 website that was created in Visual Studio 2013.  It was set up from the start to use Organizational Authentication using a single-tenant single-sign on.  There is no way to access any part of the site without logging in with an account that has the correct domain.  This is the desired function.

However, I am looking to add role-based authentication using Azure Active Directory.  The desired functionality is that some users in certain groups can see some pages, and people in other groups can see different pages, etc.  This seems like the most relevant/updated tutorial https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet.  But since I already use WS-Federation to login with an organizational account, do I really have to use OpenID type authentication as stated in the tutorial?  It seems like there should be an easy way to get the roles once I'm already logged in.  I know I probably have to use the Graph API in some sense but I don't know how.  Please advise.

Comment: I am trying to implement same functionality. Any luck with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At sign-in, when the user arrives at you app with an SSO token - your application can query the directory Graph API to determine the users group memberships. Per the group memberships you can either grant permissions to the user directly or map the group membership to a "role" in you application.

We have a topic that explains this in more detail and a sample application (that uses WSFed) to perform role-based authorization using Azure AD group memberships: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195601.aspx

Enjoy :-)